# Ancient reference to Shankaracharya by name

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

Has any ancient non-advaitic acharya/author referred to Shankaracharya by name in his work? For example I understand that Bhaskara in his Brahmasutra bhashya does not refer to Shankara by name.

Comment: I believe ramanuja and madhwa denigrated Sankara.  is that the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: No, I am not asking about that. I know Ramanuja has referred to Shankara as 'pracchanna bauddha, a fraudulent Vedantin, one endowed with primordial sinful vasanas, etc.' I just wanted to know if some ancient work mentioned Shankara by his name.  I know Vedanta Desika in his Gita commentary says '.......and Shankara  are vaishnavas.' But has any earlier author mentioned his name?